# How to pass multiple values into a dictionary

Tags: python

so i have the following code:

```
    {'stu_name': 'Abel', 'sex': 'male', 'score': 90, 'cls_id': 1},
    {'stu_name': 'Carl', 'sex': 'male', 'score': 80, 'cls_id': 2},
    {'stu_name': 'Cecil', 'sex': 'female', 'score': 60, 'cls_id': 1},
    {'stu_name': 'Elijah', 'sex': 'female', 'score': 70, 'cls_id': 2},
    {'stu_name': 'Dick', 'sex': 'male', 'score': 90, 'cls_id': 3},
    {'stu_name': 'Donald', 'sex': 'male', 'score': 80, 'cls_id': 3},
    {'stu_name': 'Jack', 'sex': 'male', 'score': 80, 'cls_id': 2},
    {'stu_name': 'Laurent', 'sex': 'female', 'score': 90, 'cls_id': 1},
    {'stu_name': 'Rex', 'sex': 'female', 'score': 90, 'cls_id': 1},
    {'stu_name': 'Tom', 'sex': 'male', 'score': 70, 'cls_id': 2},
    {'stu_name': 'Roy', 'sex': 'female', 'score': 90, 'cls_id': 3},
    {'stu_name': 'Steve', 'sex': 'male', 'score': 70, 'cls_id': 1}
]
cls_list = [
    {'id': 1, 'cls_name': 'Class One'},
    {'id': 2, 'cls_name': 'Class Two'},
    {'id': 3, 'cls_name': 'Class Three'},
    {'id': 4, 'cls_name': 'Class Four'}
]
```

What i want, is to make the program output the class name, followed by the number of people in it, followed by the number of males in it and finally followed by the number of females. What I have so far is this:

```
lst_empty = {}
for cls in cls_list:
    lst_empty.setdefault(cls['cls_name'], 0)
    for stu in stu_list:
      if stu['cls_id'] == cls['id']:
          lst_empty[cls['cls_name']] +=1
      if stu['sex'] == 'male':
```

since setdefault can only get me 2 items, I'm kind of stuck on what to do with the if sex = male bit.
I guess my main question is how do I pass in the number of males into the empty dictionary.
I don't want to drastically change my code, I just want to know what I can do with the code I have right now.
Thanks!

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to use dictionaries or can you convert them into dataframes? since with dataframes you can sort this far easier

Comment: Also do you want `lst_empty` to be a list of dicts?

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre well at the moment if its not a dictionary, I can only use a list....sorry

Comment: and regarding your second question, preferably not, but if it comes to it then ill reconsider

Answer (score 0):

I have made `lst_empty` as a list of dicts. The code is as follows:

```
stu_list = [{'stu_name': 'Abel', 'sex': 'male', 'score': 90, 'cls_id': 1},
            {'stu_name': 'Carl', 'sex': 'male', 'score': 80, 'cls_id': 2},
            {'stu_name': 'Cecil', 'sex': 'female', 'score': 60, 'cls_id': 1},
            {'stu_name': 'Elijah', 'sex': 'female', 'score': 70, 'cls_id': 2},
            {'stu_name': 'Dick', 'sex': 'male', 'score': 90, 'cls_id': 3},
            {'stu_name': 'Donald', 'sex': 'male', 'score': 80, 'cls_id': 3},
            {'stu_name': 'Jack', 'sex': 'male', 'score': 80, 'cls_id': 2},
            {'stu_name': 'Laurent', 'sex': 'female', 'score': 90, 'cls_id': 1},
            {'stu_name': 'Rex', 'sex': 'female', 'score': 90, 'cls_id': 1},
            {'stu_name': 'Tom', 'sex': 'male', 'score': 70, 'cls_id': 2},
            {'stu_name': 'Roy', 'sex': 'female', 'score': 90, 'cls_id': 3},
            {'stu_name': 'Steve', 'sex': 'male', 'score': 70, 'cls_id': 1}]

cls_list = [{'id': 1, 'cls_name': 'Class One'},
            {'id': 2, 'cls_name': 'Class Two'},
            {'id': 3, 'cls_name': 'Class Three'},
            {'id': 4, 'cls_name': 'Class Four'}]

lst_empty = []
for cls in cls_list:
    dct = {}

    dct.setdefault(cls['cls_name'], 0)
    dct.setdefault('male', 0)
    for stu in stu_list:
        if stu['cls_id'] == cls['id']:
            dct[cls['cls_name']] +=1
            if stu['sex'] == 'male':
                dct["male"] += 1
    dct["female"] = dct[cls["cls_name"]] - dct["male"]

    lst_empty.append(dct)

for i in lst_empty:
    print(i)
```

The output is:

```
{'Class One': 5, 'male': 2, 'female': 3}
{'Class Two': 4, 'male': 3, 'female': 1}
{'Class Three': 3, 'male': 2, 'female': 1}
{'Class Four': 0, 'male': 0, 'female': 0}
```

Comment: Just a side note, it should also contain `finally followed by the number of females`.

Comment: Done. Had missed that earlier

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, yet not ideal solution is:

```
for cls in cls_list:
    cls_students = list(filter(lambda s: s['cls_id'] == cls['id'], stu_list))
    cls_males    = list(filter(lambda s: s['sex']    == 'male'   , cls_students))
    cls_females  = list(filter(lambda s: s['sex']    == 'female' , cls_students))
    print(cls['cls_name'])
    print(f"Total students: {len(cls_students)}")
    print(f"Num of males:   {len(cls_males)   }")
    print(f"Num of females: {len(cls_females) }")
```

But you better consider `pandas` library with its convenient `DataFrame`s

Answer (score 0):

Just use `dict.get`:

```
dct = {}

for stu in stu_list:
    if stu['cls_id'] == cls['id']:
        dct[cls['cls_name']] = dct.get(cls['cls_name'], 0) + 1
        # will handle both 'male' and 'female' cases
        dct[stu['sex']] = dct.get(stu['sex'], 0) + 1

lst_empty.append(dct)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could setdefault an empty list or another dictionnary.

```
lst_empty.setdefault(cls['cls_name'], [0, 0, 0])
```

or

```
lst_empty.setdefault(cls['cls_name'], {"nb_people" : 0, "nb_male" : 0, "nb_female" : 0})
```

Comment: about the first line of code, how would I add to say...the second 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way if you want the result top be stored in a dict:

```
cls_dict = {}


for cls in cls_list:
    cls_dict[cls['id']]={}
    cls_dict[cls['id']]['id']=cls['id']
    cls_dict[cls['id']]['cls_name']=cls['cls_name']
    cls_dict[cls['id']]['population']=0
    cls_dict[cls['id']]['males']=0
    cls_dict[cls['id']]['females']=0


for stu in stu_list:
    if stu['cls_id'] in cls_dict:
        id = stu['cls_id']
        if stu['sex']=='female':
            cls_dict[id]['females']+=1
            cls_dict[id]['population']+=1
        elif stu['sex']=='male':
            cls_dict[id]['males']+=1
            cls_dict[id]['population']+=1
            

print(cls_dict)
```

The output will be:

```
{1: {'id': 1, 'cls_name': 'Class One', 'population': 5, 'males': 2, 'females': 3},
 2: {'id': 2, 'cls_name': 'Class Two', 'population': 4, 'males': 3, 'females': 1},
 3: {'id': 3, 'cls_name': 'Class Three', 'population': 3, 'males': 2, 'females': 1},
 4: {'id': 4, 'cls_name': 'Class Four', 'population': 0, 'males': 0, 'females': 0}}
```